# NMI watchdog: Watchdog detected hard LOCKUP on cpu

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, cpu, ubuntu-16.04, kvm

i'm using kvm on ubuntu 16.04

my machine cpu is 24 core and I run 47 sandbox using hyperthreading on kvm.
virtual macine use 0.5 core physically

After a few minutes of running kvm, the following message pops up.

i entered "iostat", it comes out

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle

```
      46.42    0.00    5.87    6.87    0.00   40.83
```

Please tell me why and how to solve the error.

[image: error message]

Comment: You may be able to get an answer quicker on [Unix & Linux StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com).

Comment: This might be this [known kernel bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=196161)? There doesn't seem to be any decent workaround, however.